# HTML: Compare input with a preset value

Tags: html, input, comparison

Simple and stupid question: I want to get a value in HTML and check if it equals a preset value.

If I were to write that in Java, it'd be like this:

```
if (sc.nextLine().equals("preset")){//sc is a Scanner(System.in) already declared above
//do stuff
}
else{
//do stuff
}
```

I know near to nothing about HTML and promised I'd have this done for a friend for something in school. It was a stupid move. Now I'm stuck banging my head to my table, reading tutorials and missing something very important.
I know it's a stupid question, but I really need help. I know nothing of html and/or php and any help would be welcome.

Comment: See answer below - javascript is a bear compared to java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started. (javascript and html - you'll notice that javascript is not strongly typed, so swapping ints, etc. for the string will have a good chance of still working - this is not always a good thing.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<p id="value">No good deed goes unpunished.</p>
<p id="value2">6</p>

<script>
var preset = "No good deed goes unpunished."
var val = document.getElementById("value");
if (JSON.stringify(val.innerText) == "\"No good deed goes unpunished.\""){
    document.write("Kind, not stupid!<br><br>");
    }

// Scandalously lifted from another SO answer...
function strcmp(a, b){   
    return (a < b ? -1 : ( a > b ? 1 : 0 ));  
}

var preset2 = 6;
var val2 = document.getElementById("value2");

if(strcmp(preset2, val2) == 0){
    document.write("Always kind, but not stupid!");
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```